# How to create and write a log file in for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, logging

I have a folder where there are huge no. of files, I want to create a log file where i can see how many files are processed till now, how can I do that.

I want to write the "root" variable in the log file.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + name
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath,index_col=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a logger

```py
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler("mylog.log", maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Add logger statement to your loop.

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + name
        logger.info(root) #Logs when level is set to Info.
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath,index_col=False)
```

Comment: How do i remove the log error

--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 70, in emit
    self.doRollover()

Comment: Are you importing logger?

Comment: Yes I am importing them.

at every iteration i am getting these

--- Logging error ---

Comment: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\GD\\mylog.log' -> 'C:\\Users\\GD\\mylog.log.1'
Call stack:

Comment: Increase `maxBytes` to a higher number eg:  `maxBytes=200000000`

Answer (score 0):

you can use somenthig like this if you dont use logging module :

```py
import os

log_file = 'log_files.txt'
mode = 'a' if os.path.exists(log_file) else 'w'



with open(log_file , mode) as f :
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir): 
        for name in files: 
             filepath = root + os.sep + name 
             f.write(filepath)
             <your code>
```